# Change output folder for Android R.java in Eclipse when using Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, m2eclipse, android-maven-plugin

I have an android project setup using the maven-android plugin.  This plugin adheres to maven output folders for the location of the `R.java` file (i.e. `target/generated-sources/r`).

However, when using this project in Eclipse, I can't configure aapt to rely on that folder.

Even if I manually go into the project properties and set up the folders manually, the ADT plugin goes in and *resets* just some of the settings (i.e. adds the `/gen` folder back as a source folder, and restores the output folder to `/bin/classes` instead of `/target/classes`), while leaving the maven `/target/generated-sources/r` folder and breaking the build of the project.

I would like to use the default Maven folder structure with the Eclipse ADT.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks

---

Responding to the comments:

- Yes, am using the m2e-android plugin.
- Because ADT is still generating R.java in `/gen`, Eclipse is failing to compile if there still exists an R.java under `target/generated-sources/r` due to duplicated class definitions.

Comment: Are you using the m2e-android plugin?

Comment: _while leaving the maven /target/generated-sources/r folder and breaking the build of the project._ Can you explain what is broken when building project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Android Connector for M2E](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android) does not support moving generated folders like the ADT gen folder to other directories. This is a restriction of the ADT, although there is a ticket to explore a way around this restriction:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/68

If you'd like to stay updated, please comment on this ticket.

Comment: aapt allows one to specify a custom folder for the generated folder (using the -J switch). I sthe Android Connector relying on aapt under the covers?  I'll follow the ticket you mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: No the Android Connector just relies on the ADT which uses the internal sdklib to build stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me:

Let the ADT keep gen as a source folder, but change the output folder for that source folder to be `/target/classes`.

I can build in both eclipse and using maven from the command line, and I don't get duplicate R class problems in either case.  Essentially, Eclipse generates the `R.java` file in `/gen`, while maven generates it in `/target/generated-sources/r`, but both builds put the `R.class` file under /target/classes.

Note: at one point I had added `/gen` as an additional source directory in my `pom.xml` using `build-helper-maven-plugin`, and I had to remove that.