# Roboelectric, Maven and the plight of the output folder

Tags: java, android, m2eclipse, robolectric, android-maven-plugin

Dear awesome community,

I have decided to bite the bullet and put together some proper TDD/BDD testing infrastructure for my Android application. I am looking to incorporate [Roboelectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/user-guide.html) in my separate test project in order prevent me from having to launch an emulator for anything remotely Android-y. To see what's what I have imported into my (Eclipse ADT 3.8) environment the RoboElectricSample project found [here](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample). But I've hit a snag... everything is working swimmingly compilation wise and I've worked around the familiar `/bin`, `/target` maven-eclipse stand-off with the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087690/eclipse-maven-junit-tests-not-compiled-when-running-them/8895652#8895652) which I can't upvote enough.

However, out of the sample project's tests (all 87 of them) only 7 pass with the remainder falling over with;

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pivotallabs.R
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at org.robolectric.AndroidManifest.getRClass(AndroidManifest.java:100)
```

Currently my `src/test/java` build output location is relative at `target/test-classes` with my `src/main/java` build output location at `target/classes`.

For completeness here is the project structure;

[image: RoboelectricSample project structure]

[This Q&A exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091226/change-output-folder-for-android-r-java-in-eclipse-when-using-maven) seems to suggest I might be barking up the wrong tree but that was over a year ago now and the m2e-android plugin has come a long way. Finally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645885/robolectric-2-1-and-eclipse) seems to reflect my problem exactly but alas with no resolution.

Any help you can provide with fixing my build path to get the `/gen/r` file to be recognised under the Maven equivalent `generated-sources/r` most appreciated. I'd like to get the sample app up and running before switching my app over to Roboelectric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Having read [this discussion](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52) against the *m2e-android* project I added the `android.jar` to the test class path as described [here](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52#issuecomment-3561612) *and* added the `bin\classes` modification to the test class path as described [here](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52#issuecomment-10007865). I also removed some overriding dependencies that were now being pulled in by *Robolectric* (dexmaker for example) and viola, I have Android tests running Dagger DI'ed code alongside Mockito.

Life is better for TDD now.

Game on!

Comment: Gah! Getting Maven to do this has been pretty difficult and thus far I have failed. Another question for another time. Hopefully by the time I need this running under CI there may be more than one of me developing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>gen/r/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>gen/r/src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your response. I was hoping that having just checked out the sample Robolectric project the solution would be configuration rather than code/XML based. I am aware your recommended change is dependency configuration but shouldn't these samples work out-of-the-box? The latest [Travis CI build](http://ci.robolectric.org) seems to think everything is a-OK. Could it be that the Eclipse JUnit runner just isn't up to the job and Maven has to be performing the builds?